# Pre-Release and Build Version Numbers in NuGet

Tags: nuget, semantic-versioning, version-numbering, build-numbers

What is considered a pre-release package in NuGet, is it anything that has a dash followed by something e.g. `1.0.0-something`?

Also, how can you use a build number using NuGet? The NuGet docs about [versioning](https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning) say that you can use `1.0.0-build123`. However, does this mean that anything with a build number has to be pre-release?

Is it possible to include a build number but not have a pre-release NuGet package?

Answer (score 0):

I created a PowerShell script to enable build Prerelease version of NuGet package by automated TFS Build. The idea is following:

1. Building the project by TFS Build
2. Pick out the output assembly version number
3. Use the version number and some constant string to set `NuGet.exe -Version` parameter

See more in my [blog post](https://kalcik.net/2016/02/09/publish-nuget-release-and-prerelease-packages-by-tfs-automated-build/).